# Add ClassLibrary Project programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I have a VS 2017 extension and have tried using my own custom Project Template, by adding it programmatically, but things aren't going so well. 
In my endeavour to find the mistake, I would like to see whether it is my custom Project Template causing the problem or not. Therefore I want to programmatically add any other existing built-in VS project such as a ClassLibrary type project template.
It seems to be located here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\

But there isn't a zip folder and I can't create one in that directory according to Windows.

I will be using something similar to the following code:

```
Solution2 soln = (Solution2)visualStudioInstance.Solution;
string templatePath = soln.GetProjectTemplate("ClassLibrary.zip", "CSharp");
soln.AddFromTemplate(templatePath, projPath, "MyProjectName", false);
```

Am I on the right track? 
I've tried it and I got an exception, but perhaps it was just because the zip folder doesn't exist.

**UPDATE**

The exception I get is:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I get it in the last line of the following code, when I try to add a reference to calcEngineProject. calcEngineProject is null even though it enters the if-statement and should be assigned the value of `projCS.Object as VSProject2`.

The code is as follows:

```
            templatePath = soln.GetProjectTemplate("ClassLibrary.zip", "CSharp");              
            soln.AddFromTemplate(templatePath, prjPath, "ClassLibrary1", false);

            foreach (Project p in soln.Projects)
            {
                if (String.Compare(p.Name, "ClassLibrary1") == 0)
                {
                    projCS = p;
                    break;
                }
            }               

            if (projCS != null)
            {
                calcEngineProject = projCS.Object as VSProject2;
            }

         calcEngineProject.References.Add(Path.Combine(Config.Engine.EngineBinPath, "Engines.Calculation.dll"));
```

Also, I saw that templatePath is this:

> "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL
>   STUDIO\2017\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\EYXTAMKA.FB4\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\.NET
>   Standard\1033\ClassLibrary\ClassLibrary.vstemplate"

and not

> \%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Exported Templates\

as mentioned in [Upgrading custom project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/upgrading-custom-project-and-item-templates-for-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Adding the exception to your post will make it easier to help.

Comment: Please see the update to the post.

Comment: That means projCS.Object is null or not of type VSProject2.

Comment: Yes. Am I using an incorrect path to the ClassLibrary template then? How do I create a normal ClassLibrary project programmatically?